# Find derivation (dB/decade) for given amplitude characteristic of low pass filter [Hz, -]

Tags: logarithms, approximation, applications, filters

I am trying to find derivation (differential attenuation) for frequency's 600 and 2000 Hz for given amplitude characteristic of low pass filter, which look like this: 
[image]

I assume, that I should transform my approximation (graph) to dB form, but how should I do this (if I am right).

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the *slope* of the tangent lines to the curve at the frequencies $600$ and $2000$ Hz represented in a [Bode plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) with two logarithmic scales instead of two linear ones as in your plot. The horizontal axis of the [low pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) should measure the frequency in [decades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decade_%28log_scale%29) and the vertical axis should measure the amplitude in [decibels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) (dB). The frequencies whose magnitudes differ by a factor of ten such as  $1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000$ Hz are equaly spaced and in general two frequencies $f_1,f_2$ are

$$\log_{10}\left(\frac{f_1}{f_2}\right)$$

decades apart. So from $100$ and $600$ Hz are $\log_{10}\left(\frac{600}{100}\right)\approx 0.778$ decades and from $2000$ to $1000$ Hz are $\log_{10}\left(\frac{2000}{1000}\right)\approx 0.301$ decades. To transform the amplitude $A_1$ in a dB change with respect to the amplitude $A_0$ use the conversion formula (if the amplitude in your plot is a voltage and not a power)

$$\text{Gain}_\mathrm{ dB} =20 \log_{10} \left (\frac{A_1}{A_0} \right ), $$

because  a change in voltage by a factor of $10$ is a $20$ dB change and means a change in power by a factor of $100=10^2$, assuming that the power is proportional to the square of the voltage. (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Definition)). The attenuation is the opposite of the gain.